# Consequences of force/no-force when committed page has dirty data

Tags: database

Given the following scenario: two transactions are writing to the same page (not necessarily the same object). On of them commits, the other doesn't. The page contains dirty data from the uncommitted transaction.

1. With force, will this page be written to the disk, even though it contains dirty data?

Given the scenario where there is space left in the buffer pool.

2. With no-force, is there a possibility of dirty page being written to disk (steal and no-steal seems irrelevant as there is still space left)?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? What "force" and "no-force" are you referring to? Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: I'm honestly talking about the general concept of force and no-force, not specific to any dbms.